# What would prevent multiple Trojan horses from materializing in the same space?

Tags: magic, alternate-worlds, gods

This is a follow up question to this: [What would make purity a necessity for an Eldritch being?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/164442/what-would-make-purity-a-necessity-for-an-eldritch-being)

The barrier separating our realm fro  the outer realm is designed to detect and prevent it from foreign essence.The cult of Narly have succeeded in their goals, and the avatar has been born into the world. As Nyarlathotep has not transferred his full essence into his avatar, it was able to slip past the barrier separating the realms, not being seen as a threat. As the avatar grows, more of Narly's essence will be transferred into it, eventually allowing the deity to fully materialize into the world.

However, this plans falls short on some level. Their are other outer gods who exist that are just as powerful if not more so than this god. They have their own designs for this world, and would seek to get in Narly's way of world conquest. Beings such as Yog-Sogoloth, Shub Niggarath, Cthulu, etc are aware of its plans, and there is nothing preventing them from reincarnating themselves into the world in the same way. There are also other good gods who created the barrier in the first place to protect humans from these Eldritch deities. They could also slip past their own safeguards with their own avatars with the intent of stopping him.

What would prevent these competing gods from using Narly's method of summoning himself into the material world?

Answer (score 2):

### The stars are wrong

Nyarlathotep can only create an avatar when Mars and Jupiter are in conjunction.  Cthulhu has to wait until Jupiter and Saturn are in conjunction, which won't happen for another three centuries.

### The cults are wrong

Nyarlathotep needed their cult in order to be summoned into their avatar.  Their cult is the only one that knows the ritual.

### The Gods are slow

The more powerful Elder Gods are also slower.  They can create avatars same as Nyarlathotep , but it takes five times as long for their avatar to become empowered than it did Nyarlathotep.

### The avatars are dead

The heroic investigators got wind of the avatar making plans, and raided the cults.  Most of the avatars were found and killed, but Nyarlathotep got away.